# How to view my actual data which i have pushed to Kinesis data stream ?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to fetch records from Kinesis Data Stream.

Here is my code.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var kinesis = new AWS.Kinesis({region: 'us-east-1'});
var params = {
  ShardIterator: 'AAAAAAAAAAGxAQOmSj54ysG1T+k+V3r7T4b4lC6TopuCy2tcyjpAYGMLO+A5ICkeEMhRd5CH2jNqu7ZQpKsr19leAndgedXhM2hygQjEIYvwJPTyVc5rwerewsdfserreJXnI8+uRa123TjF/07lUTrJf2PMGoNL3+4HXaS1TgPrcTX2OdP4K0Dz8tIz613WWYtvh3paw+g07Jz/2Xlt/e+4L', 
  Limit: 1
};
kinesis.getRecords(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

I am getting the following output in return.

```
{ Records: 
   [ { SequenceNumber: '49580243932170249199867439514950526887184270832636526594',
       ApproximateArrivalTimestamp: 2018-01-01T10:19:12.782Z,
       Data: <Buffer 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 56 69 73 68 6e 75 20 48 61 70 70 79 20 4e 65 77 20 59 65 61 72 20 21 21 21>,
       PartitionKey: 'testpartition' } ],
  NextShardIterator: 'AAAAAAAAAAGno9O2jSEPA6Amt4Fad1nP/7VvLjlT0dQhKF1MMqA+gQpS5yPRqHECbrvbxekP5wt35m0On0gnID6aMadRI1arG+EDYzpFvpBEtf1/CGssIVQIoWx3IHjU2cbay4qc242+NyMoTX05LpQqNIlCEru/935W2yZR4unsdzWiguVqCWY6KHgt8vrDueu+52gJ3lUeEpiRhUHSLvMCSqfCAmAv',
  MillisBehindLatest: 576000 }
```

How to view my actual data which i have pushed ?

The `Data parameter` returns some junk values which is not the actual data what i have pushed to.

How to view my actual data which i have pushed ? thanks in advance.

Comment: Kinesis is returning "Hello Vishnu Happy New Year !!!". What did you send to Kinesis?

Comment: records[].Data can contain anything that you want. A string, JSON, binary data, etc. For a string: const recordData = record[0].Data.toString('utf-8');

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS Management console and view it.

See: https://aws.amazon.com/it/about-aws/whats-new/2022/10/amazon-kinesis-data-streams-capability-inspect-data-records-aws-management-console/